# Why is mysql giving me an error?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am using node.js with node-mysql to execute my queries.
Here is the code I am using:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbconfig.database);
connection.query('USE '+ dbconfig.database);

connection.query('drop table if exists `ANSWER`; \
drop table if exists `ANSWERTYPE`; \
drop table if exists `COURSE`; \
drop table if exists `COURSEINSTANCE`; \
drop table if exists `ENROLL`; \
drop table if exists `FACULTY`; \
drop table if exists `QUESTION`; \
drop table if exists `QUESTIONGROUP`; \
drop table if exists `SEMESTER`; \
drop table if exists `STUDENTS`; \
drop table if exists `TEACHER`; \
........
```

However node keeps on displaying an error:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop table if exists `ANSWERTYPE`; drop table if exists `COURSE`; drop table if ' at line 1
```

Although I am pretty sure my queries are correct and I tested them manually. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try one statement at a time. `;` is a convenience for humans and isn't used by most database connectors.

Comment: Do you think its a better idea if i should I put each line in a different connection.query? @tadman

Comment: I think it's a better idea if your code works, and that's the way you get it working.

Comment: @tadman Thank you will try it out

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for drop table is:

```
DROP [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF EXISTS] [/*COMMENT TO SAVE*/]
    tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
    [RESTRICT | CASCADE]
```

so you can put one table behind the next like

```
drop table if exists `ANSWER`, `ANSWERTYPE`, `COURSE`, `COURSEINSTANCE`;
```

so its only one statement